# C# - How to retrieve an array from json dynamic object?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, type-conversion

I am trying to get the array directly from the JSON "data" item into an array variable:

```
string jsonString = "{\"data\":[
                       {\"name\":false,\"number\":true},
                       {\"name\":false,\"number\":false},
                       {\"name\":true,\"number\":false}
                     ]}";

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });
dynamic jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(object));

Array jsonArray = jsonObject.data;
// Here error says:
//Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Array' 

dynamic lastJsonArrayData = jsonArray[jsonArray.Length - 1];
// this is where the error occurs, it says:
//Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Array'
```

and last thing that I need to do is to convert `lastJsonArrayData` back to dynamic object but I dont know how.. And I need the last two steps to be performed separately as it stated, it means first to get the array then get the object!!
I am a total newbie in C#

**EDIT:** 
The real JSON structure is actually more like this:

```
string jsonString = "{\"firstlevel\":{\"secondlevel\":{\"data\":[
                       {\"name\":false,\"number\":true},
                       {\"name\":false,\"number\":false},
                       {\"name\":true,\"number\":false}
                     ]}}}";
```

Comment: Actually I also need to put the array into foreach loop..

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Actually the error seems to occur in the second step:

Comment: **What does the error say?**

Comment: It says: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Array'

Comment: That's because you aren't using `dynamic` there.

Comment: Actually I am using it I just corrected here: dynamic lastJsonArrayData

Comment: Sorry, one more mistake, now corrected: "dynamic lastJsonArrayData = jsonArray[jsonArray.Length - 1];"

Comment: Actually now error occurs also here: Array jsonArray = jsonObject.data; It says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Array'

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Today is my first day of programing in C#, so I kind of dont understand anything..

Comment: I dont know what I am supposed to do to make it work..

Comment: Try changing your line that sets the array to "Array jsonArray = jsonObject.data.ToArray();". The jsonObject.data is returning a generic list that should be an option on the list type.

Comment: Joel: That doesnt work either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var jsonArray = jsonObject.data.ToArray();
```

(Joel gave me a hint. But he declared `Array jsonArray`. And it didnt work.)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a class to map the serialised content 
I meant , you need a create class of

```
public class Example{
   public string name;
  public string number;
}
```

and here you need to change it to

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });
                dynamic jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(Example));
```

Hope this reference gives you a better understanding about serialization and desrialization

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

[Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Hope this helps

Comment: I posted here the simplest possible structure of JSON just as an example. But my real JSON contains thousands of items and the structure is far more complicated than this..

Comment: So did you try to change the lines of code i have suggested...Is it still the same problem?

Comment: Plus I tried your solution on the simple JSON and still doesnt work.

Comment: hey check if this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object